# How to call setTimeOut on a component class

Tags: reactjs, function, class, settimeout

After calling setTimeOut(Question, 3000) I receive the error "Cannot call a class as a function". "Question" needs to be a class in order to get the lifecycle methods that classes receive.

The only answer I have found so far is to include "extends React.Component" on the class, which I have.

```
import React from 'react';
import Question from './Question';

setTimeout(Question, 3000);


function Congratulations(props) {
    return(
        <div>
        <h1>Congraulations you are the champion.</h1>
        <h2>Your Score: {props.score}</h2>
    </div>
    )
}  
export default Congratulations;
```

The first few lines of Question component class follows.

```
export default class Question extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
```

I would like for Question to appear on the DOM after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use in componentdidmount method and set state for show after 3 seconds. In render method, you can render only if show is true.

In the constructor method, create a state with show = false.

In componentDidMount yo can create

```
setTimeOut(() => this.setState({ show: true}), 3000)
```

In render method you can render with that state

```
{
 show &&
  // render what you want
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. For future viewers, I would edit your post to setTimeout... Thanks, Fernando! I do have a follow-up question. Do you know what the, I assume to be, conditional statement in your render is called? I have not seen that syntax, and I would like to do further reading. (I am obviously new to this.)

Comment: If you refer to &&, that the operator tu eval the first arg (this case show) and if this is true, returns or render the sentence after &&.
Also you have || that means 'or'. you can use with variable to eval the first arg too. 
 const test = true || 'string'
Its mean, if the first arg is true, test is equal to true. If not, is equal to 'string'.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout isn't your problem, you just don't have Reacts setup code. Check out [React-Dom's render method.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) You need to wrap the setup code in a function and then trigger that function with `setTimeout`. Even a React function component isn't going to do much if you call it directly, like what `setTimeout` would do.